# Target Api 29 on Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, firemonkey

Google Play is showing me a message that before 2 of November I have to update all my apps to API 29. The fact is that I don't know how to do that.

I actually have the version 10.3.3 of Delphi.

Can somebody help me do this? Thanks.

Comment: Your apps are now api .... ?

Comment: @blackapps I think I have API 28

Comment: Dont think. Look it up. Probably you can change it where you found it. You have to download sdk 30 first. Know where you can do that.

Comment: @blackapps I don't really know how to download the sdk 30. I found this on AndroidManifest.xml in the app folder, but I think I can not edit it just as simple as change the number... I need to do more things and change something about the environment options of Delphi, but I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: You need Android SDK manager (You probably already have it). See https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Comment: First, you don't need to update your apps by November. Only if you decide to update your app after November 2, you application must support API 29 or higher. Supporting API 29 with 10.3.3 is a bit tricky. It requires manually modifying the manifest, but such application no longer works in compatibility mode and there are some issues (app crashes) like the one reported in https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27218